# Using ansible to update SSH keys for groups of servers

Tags: ansible

I'm really loving ansible, and I'd like to use it to help me manage ssh keys.  I've used small code examples as a test, and proved the basic software works as expected.

I have my servers in the hosts file, with group names like `<application><servertype><environment>`.  For example:  AlfrescoAppProd, AlfrescoDBDev, etc. These are then grouped in more logical groups, such as Prod (all production servers), DB (all database servers), etc.

Ultimately I'd like to run an "AddSSHKeys.yml" playbook, have it prompt me for the group (Prod, App, etc), have it prompt me for the location of the public key to add, then that key would be applied to all servers matching the input.

I think I'm on the right path, but wanted to verify with you fine people.  Let me know if I'm going about this the wrong way or making it more complex than necessary before I code it for all of our servers.

Thanks,

-Scott

Answer (score 0):

Ansible is not really an interactive tool. You should avoid using patterns with user interaction.

Nevertheless you can pass everything you want in command line. The simplest way is to use `-e` option (it can be repeated few times if needed). It set variable to a specified value. F.e. `ansible-playbook -i myinventory play.yaml -e "ssh_key=AAAA...."`. For more advanced things you can use lookup plugins (they can read files from localhost), and you can pass filename as variables.

For really grandiose sets of data you can use `include_vars`.